# Python3 close file handle inside Class

Tags: python-3.x, class, filehandle

I'm trying to close a file inside a Class. But whatever I try, it just stays open. So my question is simple.

Why doesn't it close?

Any help or explanation is very welcome. Thanks in advance!

```
import os
class LoopFolders:
    def __init__(self, targetFolder):
        self.targetFolder = targetFolder
        print('Target Folder:', targetFolder)

    def closeFile(self):
        self.logFile.close()
        print('All done!')

    def loop(self):
        self.logFile = open('FileList.txt', 'w')
        for root, subs, files in os.walk(self.targetFolder):
            print('Root:', root)
            self.logFile.write('Root:\n'+root+'\n')
        self.closeFile()

        # This doesn't work either:
        # self.logFile.close()

# code run example
run = LoopFolders('c:/')
run.loop()
```

Comment: How do you call your class and how it doesn't work?

Comment: Also this code will raise a `SyntaxErro` because you've omitted the `def` keyword before `__init__`.

Comment: Initialization of Class is missing "s" it should be `run = LoopFolders()`

Comment: A quick test shows close is being called , i added a break statement after loop first 5

`Target Folder: c:/
Root: c:/
Root: c:/$Recycle.Bin
Root: c:/$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-147214757-305610072-1517763936-2309274
Root: c:/$WINDOWS.~BT
Root: c:/$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources
All done!`

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by placing the write parts under the with function.
Thanks again for the help!

```
import os
class LoopFolders:
    def __init__(self, targetFolder):
        self.targetFolder = targetFolder
        print('Target Folder:', targetFolder)

    def loop(self):
        with open('fileList.txt', 'w') as self.logFile:
            for root, subs, files in os.walk(self.targetFolder):
                print('Root:', root)
                self.logFile.write('Root:\n')
                self.logFile.write(root+'\n')

                print('\tSubfolders:', subs)
                self.logFile.write('\tSubfolders:\n')
                for sub in subs:
                    self.logFile.write('\t'+sub+'\n')

                print('\t\tFiles:\n')
                self.logFile.write('\t\tFiles:\n')
                for file in files:
                    try:
                        print('\t\t', file, '\n')
                        self.logFile.write('\t\t'+file+'\n')
                    except:
                        print('File in', root, 'could not be read')
                        self.logFile.write('file in '+root+' could not be read')
                        continue
            self.logFile.write('\n\n')

run = LoopFolders('C:/').loop()
```